# PDO with base64_encode works partly

Tags: php, pdo

(I always search and found answers here for many years. This is my first post, hoping I'm doing it right...)

In my user_class.php is all the code to register, verify forgot pw, send mail, etc. But also this function:

USER_CLASS.php

```
public function lastID()
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
    return $stmt;
}
```

In my signup.php everything works as expected; the row is inserted correctly into the database tbl_users, with the code from:

SIGNUP.php

```
$code = md5(uniqid(rand()));
```

Also, the email is send correctly with the activation link as in the code below.

SIGNUP.php

```
else
{
    if($reg_user->register($uname,$email,$upass,$code,$iagree,$userip))
    {           
        $id = $reg_user->lastID();      
        $key = base64_encode($id);
        $id = $key;


        $message = "                    
                    Hello $uname,
                    <br /><br />
                    Welcome to XXXXX.<br/>
                    To complete your registration  please , follow the link below:<br/>
                    <br /><br />
                    <a href='http://example.com/verify.php?id=$id&code=$code'>Click here to Activate your account.</a>
```

When I compare the the code ($code) with the code stored in the table, it is correct (the same) as it should be.

The PROBLEM is that when I follow the activation link, my verify.php page cannot find that record in the table:

VERIFY.php

```
if(empty($_GET['id']) && empty($_GET['code']))
{
    $user->redirect('index.php');
}

if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $id = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $statusY = "Y";
    $statusN = "N";

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT userID,userStatus FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uID AND tokenCode=:code LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$id,":code"=>$code));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    if($row['userStatus']==$statusN)
    {
        $stmt = $user->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET userStatus=:status WHERE userID=:uID");
        $stmt->bindparam(":status",$statusY);
        $stmt->bindparam(":uID",$id);
        $stmt->execute();   

        $msg = "
               <div class='alert alert-success'>
               <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                  <strong>Thank you.</strong>  Your Account is now activated : <a href='index.php'>Login here</a>
               </div>
               ";   
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "
               <div class='alert alert-error'>
               <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                  Your Account is already Activated : <a href='index.php'>Login here</a>
               </div>
               ";
    }
}
else
{
    $msg = "
           <div class='alert alert-error'>
           <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
           No Account Found : <a href='signup.php'>Signup here</a>
           </div>
           ";
  } 
}
```

Following the verify link from the email takes me to verify.php and then the error:

```
$msg = "
           <div class='alert alert-error'>
           <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
           No Account Found : <a href='signup.php'>Signup here</a>
           </div>
           ";
```

The PROBLEM, I think, is in signup.php, specifically with $key :

```
$id = $reg_user->lastID();      
$key = base64_encode($id);
$id = $key;
```

The reason i think it's $key, is because the email's verify-account link looks like this:

http://www.example.com/verify.php?id=MTUz&code=c74f01c3ea3edf807b21fc4ea28a41cb

Now, I clearly don't know much, and I admit at being a beginner, but the MTUz bit is what seems the be the issue. The only thing I could come up with is that the MTU is something to do woth exceeding the size of something.

I admit that I haven't tried anything else because I don't know where to start.

Please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

CREDIT to the original author of the script:
codingcage(dot)com/2015/09/login-registration-email-verification-forgot-password-php.html

Comment: `MTUz` is simply `153` in base64 representation. Any reason you're b64ing what appears to only ever be an integer?

Comment: Thank you. The code is as I got it from the credit link in my post. The issue is not so much why base64 is used, but rather : Is the base64 code generated correctly, and if so, why does it not decode as in my post's verify.php code. Is there a better alternative to the base64?

Comment: are you sure it didn't decode correctly? a lot of your code is simply assuming nothing could fail. basic debugging: `var_dump($_GET)`, see what was received, `var_dump($id)` to see what got decoded, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAJOR FAIL on my part.

@Marc B - thank you, `var_dump($_GET)` is what pointed out my mistake.

I apologize profoundly for taking up your time with my stupid mistake.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with any of the code, except for the following in user_class.php:

```
public function lastID()
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
    return $stmt;
}
```

Specifically `lastInsertId();`

This last id is of course what the verify.php is looking for:

```
$id = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
```

This all works correctly as it should.

The problem (MY mistake) was this:

I had two INSERT INTO statements;

FIRTS > INSERT INTO tbl_user < the new signup user.

SECOND > INSERT INTO tbl_another < stuff I need.

So obviously `lastInsertId();' was taking the ID from tbl_another.

And lastInsertId is just that, >> LAST <<

I simply change the order of the INSERT INTO so that tbl_users' ID is last

All now works correctly. I feel such an idiot - spend days on it and then out of desperation - sought help here.

Thank you for your time anyway.
Jamie.

PS: How do I mark this post as SOLVED ?
[EDIT] Found it - click the check-mark to accept answer, correct? but can do so only tomorrow.